# how to render React components with props from client

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm adding React to an existing asp.net web forms app. I don't want to create a node environment inside the production server. I have set up my development environment with babel and webpack, and I can successfully render React components into the client-side html by including a  in the client-side html and a React.render() call inside the react source code. I want to call the render function from the client-side html, so that I can pass props to the component.

i've tried exporting a function that takes the mountnode and props, and calls React.render() but i don't know how

index.html

```
<b id="react_container">this is where react will live</b>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/react/dist/bundledRODT.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

            var reactElement = React.createElement('RODT', { data:"hello world" });
            ReactDOM.render(
                reactElement,
                document.getElementById('react_container')
            );
</script>
```

RODT.js

```
import LabelAndText from './LabelAndText.js'
import CheckBoxAndLabel from './CheckBoxAndLabel.js'
import {Component} from 'react'

class RODT extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {}
  }

  render() {
    var {
      data,
      ...otherProps
    } = this.props

    return (
      <div id="RODT" key="RODT" {...otherProps}>
       <LabelAndText />
       <CheckBoxAndLabel />
       {data}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default RecordOnDockTable
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/RODT.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundledRODT.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets:[
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/react',
            {
              'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: So it's not clear, do the code from `index.html` works? 

Also I may suggest to create empty NET.Core project with React and see how interconnection is implemented. Also you may take ready to use `webpack.config.js` from there

Comment: it doesn't. but by wrapping the component in a function and packaging RODT.js as a library it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack bundles your script. This means it encapsulates it from the outer environment. You can't call components or functions without creating a [library configuration](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary).

Add the following (example) to your webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  output: {
    library: 'MyLibrary'
  }
};
```

The variable `MyLibrary` will be bound with the return value of your entry file, if the resulting output is included as a script tag in an HTML page.

There's even a documentation on [authoring libraries](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/).